# Can I enter a value string as one condition of a view's filter?

Tags: list-view, filter

For example, could I, in one rule, filter a view based on "Show the items when column *x* contains ***a, b, or c***?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that'll be three clauses in the filter